# What is the correct way to separate sorting functionality from header clicks on a column?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a Tabulator table with a column that I want to be sortable by the user, but I also want to have a dialog appear when the user clicks on the column header to provide additional information.

I have no problem adding the headerClick function to the column definition and have all of that working, but the problem is, when the column is clicked, it also triggers the sorting to happen on that column.

Is there a way to separate these two functions so that when clicking on the sort arrow region (the right edge of the column - say the right 10%) the sorting occurs, but when clicking on the rest of the column header, the dialog appears and the sort is canceled?

I think I can use some information in the 'e' argument (a mouse event object) to detect where the cursor was/is when the click occurred, but I'm not sure how to cancel the sort.

Some sample code:

```
function headerClickHandler(e, column) {
  // Can the mouse event ('e') be used to detect the location of the cursor and cancel a sort event?
  alert('This column data will be sorted when this dialog closes!');
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    tooltips:true,
    layout:"fitColumns", 
    data:tabledata,
    movableColumns: true,

    columns:[
      {title: "Question Num", formatter:"rownum", align:"center", width:40},
      {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, headerFilter: true, headerFilterFunc:"regex"},
      {title:"Progress", field:"progress", align:"right", sorter:"number", headerFilter: true, headerFilter:true},
      {title:"Gender", field:"gender", widthGrow:2, headerClick:headerClickHandler},
      {title:"Remove", formatter:"buttonCross", width:40, align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().delete();}}
    ],
});
```

```js
// Define Test Data
var tabledata = [
{id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:-12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5},
{id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1.5, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:-1.5, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true", lucky_no:12},
{id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:10.5, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980", lucky_no:18},
{id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:-10.5, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999", lucky_no:33},
{id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:-20, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1, lucky_no:2},
{id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", progress:-10.4, gender:"male", rating:3, col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985", car:true, lucky_no:63},
{id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", progress:-10.6, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true", lucky_no:72},
{id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", progress:10.4, gender:"female", rating:1, col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970", lucky_no:44},
{id:10, name:"James Newman", progress:10.6, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998", lucky_no:9},
{id:11, name:"Martin Barryman", progress:20, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"violet", dob:"04/04/2001"},
{id:12, name:"Jenny Green", progress:56, gender:"female", rating:4, col:"indigo", dob:"12/11/1998", car:true},
{id:13, name:"Alan Francis", progress:90, gender:"male", rating:3, col:"blue", dob:"07/08/1972", car:true},
{id:14, name:"John Phillips", progress:80, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"green", dob:"24/09/1950", car:true},
{id:15, name:"Ed White", progress:70, gender:"male", rating:0, col:"yellow", dob:"19/06/1976"},
{id:16, name:"Paul Branderson", progress:60, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"orange", dob:"01/01/1982"},
{id:18, name:"Emma Netwon", progress:40, gender:"female", rating:4, col:"brown", dob:"07/10/1963", car:true},
{id:19, name:"Hannah Farnsworth", progress:30, gender:"female", rating:1, col:"pink", dob:"11/02/1991"},
{id:20, name:"Victoria Bath", progress:20, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"purple", dob:"22/03/1986"},
];


function headerClickHandler(e, column) {
  // Can the mouse event ('e') be used to detect the location of the cursor and cancel a sort event?
  alert('This column data will be sorted when this dialog closes!');
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    tooltips:true,
    layout:"fitColumns", 
    data:tabledata,
    movableColumns: true,
  
    columns:[
      {title: "Question Num", formatter:"rownum", align:"center", width:40},
      {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, headerFilter: true, headerFilterFunc:"regex"},
      {title:"Progress", field:"progress", align:"right", sorter:"number", headerFilter: true, headerFilter:true},
      {title:"Gender", field:"gender", widthGrow:2, headerClick:headerClickHandler},
      {title:"Remove", formatter:"buttonCross", width:40, align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().delete();}}
    ],
});
```

```css
#example-table{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a span element that fills most of your TH (except for the "sort" icon), and is positioned (z-index) on top of everything else. Attach your custom event handler to that span. In your handler, preventDefault and stopPropagation. When you're ready for the sort, call .click() on the TH (or whatever element Tabulator listens for). Also, don't specify a callback via Tabulator's API (remove all of the columns headerClick:headerClickHandler)

Comment: I looked at Tabulator's documentation and I didn't see any built-in way to accomplish your desired goal ... like "pause the sort until I call it"

Comment: I'm attempting to implement your suggestion, using the method suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438218/2136313, but so far haven't been successful.  I'm in Angular 7, and it appears that answer is using jQuery... I've just got to figure out the equivalent.  I may see if I can resurrect an issue listed on github for Tabulator: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/675.  My goal is similar, but the proposed solution doesn't work for me since I still want to have the ability to sort.

Comment: You should be able to use Angular and jQuery in the same project. That said, click() is vanilla javascript so you don't need jQuery. Just to test things, you could start with the span (or div) outside of the table to begin with ... write a click handler for the span and in that handler call .click() on the TH.

Comment: I'm marking yours as the answer since it led me in the right direction.  I've submitted a separate answer with my implementation to help others who may need something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Ted-Fitzpatrick's answer as a starting point, along with information from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438218/2136313, I was able to do the following change to get the functionality I was looking for.

```
function headerClickHandler(e, column) {
  alert('This alert will appear when clicking on the left 90% area of the column header and no sorting will be done!');
}

function customColumnHeaderClicked(e, cell) {
  // The following two lines will block the default sort event from being triggered
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  // My header click event handler needed the column reference object normally passed in from Tabulator (not shown in the provided sample).  
  // To fix this, I needed to lookup the column component from information that I did have
  const colRef = table.getColumns().find( e => e.getDefinition().title === cell.getValue());
  headerClickHandler(e, colRef);
}

// The formatter adds the span that allows me to define the click region and handle myself
function customHeaderFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
  const titleElement = document.createElement("span");
  titleElement.style.width='90%';
  titleElement.innerHTML = cell.getValue();
  titleElement.onclick = (e) => customColumnHeaderClicked(e, cell);
  return titleElement; 
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    // ...
    columns:[
      // ...
      {
        // ...
        // headerClick:headerClickHandler // This should no longer be called directly
        titleFormatter: customHeaderFormatter
      },
      // ...
    ],
});
```

Below is the updated sample code demonstrating the above changes.

```js
// Define Test Data
var tabledata = [
{id:1, name:"Oli Bob", progress:-12, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1, lucky_no:5},
{id:2, name:"Mary May", progress:1.5, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", car:true, lucky_no:10},
{id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", progress:-1.5, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true", lucky_no:12},
{id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", progress:10.5, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980", lucky_no:18},
{id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", progress:-10.5, gender:"female", rating:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999", lucky_no:33},
{id:6, name:"Frank Harbours", progress:-20, gender:"male", rating:4, col:"red", dob:"12/05/1966", car:1, lucky_no:2},
{id:7, name:"Jamie Newhart", progress:-10.4, gender:"male", rating:3, col:"green", dob:"14/05/1985", car:true, lucky_no:63},
{id:8, name:"Gemma Jane", progress:-10.6, gender:"female", rating:0, col:"red", dob:"22/05/1982", car:"true", lucky_no:72},
{id:9, name:"Emily Sykes", progress:10.4, gender:"female", rating:1, col:"maroon", dob:"11/11/1970", lucky_no:44},
{id:10, name:"James Newman", progress:10.6, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"red", dob:"22/03/1998", lucky_no:9},
{id:11, name:"Martin Barryman", progress:20, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"violet", dob:"04/04/2001"},
{id:12, name:"Jenny Green", progress:56, gender:"female", rating:4, col:"indigo", dob:"12/11/1998", car:true},
{id:13, name:"Alan Francis", progress:90, gender:"male", rating:3, col:"blue", dob:"07/08/1972", car:true},
{id:14, name:"John Phillips", progress:80, gender:"male", rating:1, col:"green", dob:"24/09/1950", car:true},
{id:15, name:"Ed White", progress:70, gender:"male", rating:0, col:"yellow", dob:"19/06/1976"},
{id:16, name:"Paul Branderson", progress:60, gender:"male", rating:5, col:"orange", dob:"01/01/1982"},
{id:18, name:"Emma Netwon", progress:40, gender:"female", rating:4, col:"brown", dob:"07/10/1963", car:true},
{id:19, name:"Hannah Farnsworth", progress:30, gender:"female", rating:1, col:"pink", dob:"11/02/1991"},
{id:20, name:"Victoria Bath", progress:20, gender:"female", rating:2, col:"purple", dob:"22/03/1986"},
];


function headerClickHandler(e, column) {
  // Can the mouse event ('e') be used to detect the location of the cursor and cancel a sort event?
  alert('This column data will be sorted when this dialog closes!');
}

function customColumnHeaderClicked(e, cell) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  const colRef = table.getColumns().find( e => e.getDefinition().title === cell.getValue());
  headerClickHandler(e, colRef);
}

function customHeaderFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
  const titleElement = document.createElement("span");
  titleElement.style.width='90%';
  titleElement.innerHTML = cell.getValue();
  titleElement.onclick = (e) => customColumnHeaderClicked(e, cell);
  return titleElement; 
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    tooltips:true,
    layout:"fitColumns", 
    data:tabledata,
    movableColumns: true,
  
    columns:[
      {title: "Question Num", formatter:"rownum", align:"center", width:40},
      {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, headerFilter: true, headerFilterFunc:"regex"},
      {title:"Progress", field:"progress", align:"right", sorter:"number", headerFilter: true, headerFilter:true},
      {
        title:"Gender", 
        field:"gender", 
        widthGrow:2, 
        // headerClick:headerClickHandler
        titleFormatter: customHeaderFormatter
      },
      {title:"Remove", formatter:"buttonCross", width:40, align:"center", cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().delete();}}
    ],
});
```

```css
#example-table{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```