# Is there a way to add a headerMenu to a group column?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Column menus are a great feature of Tabulator and according to the documentation it should be possible to add it to *any* column. Unfortunately I'm not able to add one to the header of a column group. Am I doing it wrong or is this not (yet) supported? The code snippet below demonstrates the behaviour. All columns except Group1 get a menu.

If it is not supported I tend to use the solution from [Tabulator - Add menu button to column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301995/tabulator-add-menu-button-to-column-header) but there I cannot see a way to identify the column component to which the menu would belong when the formatter is executed which would be necessary as I would need to create menu items in dynamically created Tabulators and columns depending on the data of the column.

Any suggestions?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
   <div id="example-table"/>
    <script>
        var headerMenu = [
            {
                label:"<i class='fas fa-eye-slash'></i> Hide Column",
                action:function(e, column){
                    column.hide();
                }
            },
            {
                label:"<i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i> Move Column",
                action:function(e, column){
                    column.move("col");
                }
            }
        ]

        //initialize table
        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            height:"311px",
            layout:"fitColumns",
            columns:[
                {title:"Group1", headerMenu:headerMenu, columns:[
                    {title:"Name", field:"name", headerMenu:headerMenu},
                    {title:"Progress", field:"progress", hozAlign:"right", sorter:"number", headerMenu:headerMenu},]
                },
                {title:"Gender", field:"gender", headerMenu:headerMenu},
                {title:"Rating", field:"rating", hozAlign:"center", headerMenu:headerMenu},
                {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", headerMenu:headerMenu}, //add menu to this column header
            ],
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about my **real** problem I found that it would be enough to add a link with parameters to the group column head. I added this solution to my original example to ensure that this solution is somehow documented if someone runs in the same question. The link or the whole header can be customized very easily in the `menuTitleFormatter`.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table" />
<script>
  var headerMenu = [{
      label: "<i class='fas fa-eye-slash'></i> Hide Column",
      action: function(e, column) {
        column.hide();
      }
    },
    {
      label: "<i class='fas fa-arrows-alt'></i> Move Column",
      action: function(e, column) {
        column.move("col");
      }
    }
  ]

  var menuTitleFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = `<a href="/page?param1=${formatterParams.param1}&param2=${formatterParams.param2}" target="_blank">this_is_a_link</a>`;
    var title = document.createElement("span");
    title.innerHTML = cell.getValue();
    title.appendChild(span); //add menu to title      
    return title;
  }

  var titleFormatterParams = {
    param1: 'value1',
    param2: 'value2'
  };

  //initialize table
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "311px",
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [{
        title: "Group1",
        headerMenu: headerMenu,
        titleFormatter: menuTitleFormatter,
        titleFormatterParams: titleFormatterParams,
        columns: [{
            title: "Name",
            field: "name",
            headerMenu: headerMenu
          },
          {
            title: "Progress",
            field: "progress",
            hozAlign: "right",
            sorter: "number",
            headerMenu: headerMenu
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Gender",
        field: "gender",
        headerMenu: headerMenu
      },
      {
        title: "Rating",
        field: "rating",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerMenu: headerMenu
      },
      {
        title: "Favourite Color",
        field: "col",
        headerMenu: headerMenu
      }, //add menu to this column header
    ],
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Tabulator 4.7 there is built in header menu functionality, using the ***headerMenu*** option.

```js
//define row context menu
var headerMenu = [
    {
        label:"Hide Column",
        action:function(e, column){
            column.hide();
        }
    },
]

//add header menu in column definition
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, headerMenu:headerMenu}, //add menu to this column header
    ]
});
```

Checkout the [Menu Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/menu#header-menu) for full details on how to use this new functionality

Comment: This is a very nice feature, unfortunately I can't get it to work with column groups (where I add the headerMenu *only* on the leaf columns).  When clicking on the ellipses menu, I see the following error :

>  o.forEach is not a function
    at _.loadMenu 

(apologies for minified code!...this corresponds to the menu.forEach call in Menu.prototype.loadMenu function).

Comment: If you think you have found a bug, please create an issue on the GitHub repo and include a link to a JS fiddle that demonstrates the issue