# tabulator: add a button in a column header

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I tried to walk along this post: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438218/4225972) by [@oli folkerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588993/oli-folkerd).
What I want to achieve is adding this "primary" button like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

```
let someBTN = `<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>`

var table = new Tabulator("#producteditor", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    pagination: "local",
    ajaxURL: "api/products",
    columns: [{ title: "number", 
                field: "number", 
                headerFilter: "input"},
                ...
              { title: "", 
                formatter: editBTN, 
                cellClick: editCB, 
                headerSort: false},
              { title: "", 
                formatter: delBTN, 
                cellClick: delCB, 
                headerSort: false, 
                headerMenu = [ { label: someBTN, 
                                 action: "" } ] } ]
});
```

Could I also do this (pencil and trash are two different columns because they have different callbacks)?

[image]

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you sort of want to group the 2 columns under a single Header and use the <button>Primary</button> as your group Header ? If so, I dont think the column Group Header layout code will place it where you want it (level with the filters).

Since you seem to only have the 2 columns for the purpose of having 2 buttons, you might consider combining them into 1 column and using the HTML formatter to put the buttons in the column ?

Comment: it would be ok if primary button is only above the second (trash) button. can you show me how to use the HTML formatter to add the button in one column header?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're looking for. Did you want a button as the headerFilter (as drawn above) or did you want a headerMenu ? I put both in the fiddle for you to decide : https://jsfiddle.net/txv81bco/1/

Comment: or fiddle #2 https://jsfiddle.net/txv81bco/2/ where I put a button in the titleFormatter

Comment: I edited the fiddle a little bit and it now does exactly what I need: https://jsfiddle.net/dvp3Lb9r/ - would you please write an answer so I can accept it? Bonus points for your soul if you show me how to combine the two buttons into one row with different callback functions for each button.

Comment: See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aozreL60/

Comment: argh, I should have put "!= -1" in the comparison of indexOf(), but you get the idea

Comment: this works, but every other time I get: `Uncaught TypeError: el.className.indexOf is not a function`

Comment: this might be becoz el.className is not returning an array (for some reason ? not sure why). Do an Array.isArray(el.className) check first, just to be sure *but I really cant think of a reason why a DOM element would not have a className Array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a custom [editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/edit#edit-custom) that you can put in your headerFilter

```
headerFilter:function(cell, onR, success, cancel, eP) {
    let el = document.createElement('button');
    el.innerHTML = 'Primary';
    return el;
}
```