# Tabulator header filtering via drop down dialog box

Tags: javascript, frontend, tabulator

I am new to tabulator. The filtering capabilities provided by the tabulator are nice but am looking for a more compact solution. I want the filter options to be dropdowned when you click on the header so you can select the filter type and set the values. So far, when you enable the header filter it takes a complete row and doesn't look nice or you can have a separate filter element and bind it to table. Both solutions don't fit my application needs at the moment.

Is there a way to do that? I have searched on StackOverflow and found the following [Question][Tabulator - Add menu button to column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301995/tabulator-add-menu-button-to-column-header) . Attached is the screenshot of what am looking for. When you click on cost this dialog box opens up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality like this built in to Tabulator. As you mention yourself there is currently an open feature request for this

You could look at adding the functionality yourself using a [Custom Module](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/module-build)

There are several [Example Modules](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/module-examples) you can use to get started